# How many degrees of freedom does the water molecule have?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, physical-chemistry, molecules, degrees-of-freedom

This is mainly a question about molar heat capacity. I've read many different values for the degrees of freedom of water, for example f = 12 on (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_heat_capacity).

But by the Dulong-Petit law we have that $$c_m = \frac{f}{2} R = 49.9 \frac{J}{K \cdot mol}$$

which contradicts the Kopp-Neumann-law which estimates that $$c_m \approx 75 \frac{J}{K \cdot mol}$$

So f = 18 seems more appropriate here. But I've also seen authors argue that it is 3 or 6. So what's true?

Comment: Does one of these answer your question [Water molecule degrees of freedom site:physics.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=water+molecule+degrees+of+freedom+site:physics.stackexchange.com&client=firefox-b-d&sca_esv=589119146&sxsrf=AM9HkKnB2dnWfmTyQPVh1dbh5-DdxN4Sug:1702053708586&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi16MCVpICDAxXYgP0HHSQIAN0QrQIoBHoECCQQBQ&biw=1548&bih=895&dpr=1.2)?