# Difference between Kopp-Neumann and Dulong-Petit law?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, water, degrees-of-freedom

So this is basically a follow-up to this question: [How many degrees of freedom does the water molecule have?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/791667/how-many-degrees-of-freedom-does-the-water-molecule-have)

I've done some further research and found that the main difference between Dulong-Petit and Kopp-Neumann is that Dulong-Petit actually cares about the degrees of freedom of a molecule and in Kopp-Neumann you split the molecule into its parts and then use the degrees of freedom of the individual atoms.

What I haven't found out so far is why there is such a big difference in these both laws: Why does Dulong-Petit $c_\text{mol} \approx 33 \frac{\text{J}}{\text{Kmol}}$ assuming the literature value 8 degrees of freedom for the water molecule and Kopp-Neumann gives a way better result of approx. 75$\frac{\text{J}}{\text{Kmol}}$, which is way closer to the actual value of 75.338$\frac{\text{J}}{\text{Kmol}}$.

Why is Dulong-Petit so bad in this instance? When does it actually work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you'd apply Kopp-Neumann in this case - you have no mixture...
However, as to Dulong-Petit, note that it assumes quadratic degrees of freedom, and localized particles. Therefore it is mostly useful for metals in room temperature, where the heat capacity arises from the nuclei's movements. In other cases (like in low temperature metals, where the nuclei's movements are exponentially smaller due to quantum behaviors) the heat capacity is very different, and actually behaves like a cubic law $C_p \propto AT^3$.
So actually, the proper question is - why should water even behave according to Dulong-Petit? This is a model of classical solids, and it does not apply for liquids, just like it does not apply for quantum (cold) solids.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know Dulong-Petit only works for solids but I just think it's surprising that the molar heat capacity changes so much regarding on the state of the substance. As for Kopp-Neumann: I can treat water as H_2O and split it into its components.

Comment: As to D-P, I think it makes sense. The ways something can move differ between water, ice and vapor.